# Determine the region given by ${z: \Re(z-i) + \Im(\sqrt {zi}) \gt 0}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this problem:

Determine the region given by ${z: \Re(z-i) + \Im(\sqrt {zi}) \gt 0}$

Where $z$ is a complex number.

I tried to re write this using $z=x+iy$, then $\Re(z-i)=x$ and $\Im(\sqrt{xi-y})$ but still I cannot determine the region

Comment: The question is not well posed because $\sqrt {zi}$ has tow values one of which is the negative of the other.

Comment: For complex numbers it is not clear the meaning of 'sqrt'.You must specify some interval $[k,k+\pi)$ for the argument of that square root. On the other hand, note that $\text{Re}(z-i)=\text{Re}(z)$.

Comment: What does $>$ mean in this context? It is impossible to compare a complex number with a real one.